# xmpp : message protocol format

Tags: command-line, scripting, xmpp, ejabberd

I am relatively new to XMPP and Jabber protocol. I am using Ubuntu 12.0 LTS OS. I need to find out various XMPP / Japper message formats that a client needs to send to an ejabberd IM server.

Please let me know what is the easiest way to know them - like chat, shat group, file sharing etc.

Is there any standard library (with example) avaiable on Internet. I prefer to use Python for such a purpose. My aim is to develop a command line tool that can connect to ejabberd server and dump various message formats that client needs to send to an Xmpp/Jabber server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to know is here: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/

For python I believe the current favourite is sleepxmpp: https://github.com/fritzy/SleekXMPP/wiki

For a list of libraries see: http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/libraries/

Comment: Please let me which document in http://xmpp.org/xmpp-protocols/xmpp-extensions/ URL specifies the messages formats that needs to be send to Jabber/XMPP server - say for example - login/chat etc

Comment: The base XMPP specifications are RFC 6120, RFC 6121, and RFC 6122.

If you read the list on the xmpp-extensions page you will be able to tell which extension is for what functionality :)

Comment: I do understand the documents but I tried a simple search for connect to server, login authentication XMPP messages - I am unable to find it there.

Answer (score 3):

For getting started with XMPP in Python, I recommend the [SleekXMPP](http://sleekxmpp.com/) library. It provides a lot of features, and makes using XMPP very easy. The documentation is good, and it has [many simple examples](http://sleekxmpp.com/getting_started/echobot.html).

While Lloyd is correct about the protocol documentation he links to, I strongly believe that you should get started by using a ready-made library instead of trying to create everything yourself from scratch. You can do that later, if you want, once you understand XMPP more.